# Is it possible to pass multiple parameters in request url using webhdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

Is it possible to pass multiple arguments in url using webhdfs for instance like show below? `http://112.128.0.17:9870/webhdfs/v1/user/myuser/file2.txt&file1.txt?op=DELETE&user.name=myuser&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false&recursive=true`Obviously it is just an example which doesn't work but maybe there is any way to do this? Or it is needed to send multiple requests?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, besides the fact that the URL you created is not even valid.

You will need to issue one request (file operation) at a time.